# Can I send something to Israel with a Jew who is flying on shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, travel

The thing that's being sent will be given to the traveller well before shabbat and the flight leaves before shabbat.

Comment: So, just to clarify, they leave before Shabbat, but the flight continues into Shabbat?

Comment: Yes, that's right